# Toasts for Windows Phone 8.1 RuneTime?

Tags: c#, xaml, notifications, windows-phone-8.1, toast

How can you show a toastmessage for a few seconds in Windows Phone 8.1 RuneTime?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 var toastXml = 
     ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);       
     var toastText = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
     (toastText[0] as XmlElement).InnerText = "Line 1";
     var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
     toastNotifier.Show(toast);
```

"toastNotifier" cannot be found...

And is there a way to changed the background color of a toast? I just need to show a small text for a few seconds but I would like to use the same background color as the main color of my application.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line

```
  ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
```

As for the background color, it uses the phone theme accent color and I don't think it can be changed ...

Comment: I have a application where the background color is purple for a toast.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot change the background color of the toast, the toast will always use the background color of your application (specified in the manifest).  This helps you identify that the toast is coming from a particular app.  Look at the background color of your application and change it to see this.
and for toast use following code

```
            var ToastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        var ToastXML = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
        var ToastText = ToastXML.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        (ToastText[0] as XmlElement).InnerText = message;
        var ToastNode = ToastXML.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        var Toast = new ToastNotification(ToastXML);
        Toast.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(2);
        ToastNotifier.Show(Toast);
```

It should resolve your problem.